# what is the difference between execution_timeout and dagrun_timeout in airflow?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to airflow and wanted to know the difference between `execution_timeout` and `dagrun_timeout` in Airflow. Actually, in my codebase, I am currently using `execution_timeout` but some of the dags are not respecting timeout.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the documentation:

> [**execution_timeout** (datetime.timedelta)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html#timeouts) – max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.
>
> [**dagrun_timeout** (datetime.timedelta)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG) – specify how long a DagRun should be up before timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created

The `execution_timeout` refers to the execution of the TaskInstance, while the `dagrun_timeout` is about the entire DAG which can consist of many tasks.

To understand why your tasks are not respecting the timeout, you will need to provide more information, and ideally a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: to elaborate further - 'timeout' is to be used on normal tasks, and 'execution_timeout' on sensor tasks

Comment: @phenderbender thats not what the docs say: "If you want a task to have a maximum runtime, set its execution_timeout attribute to a datetime.timedelta value that is the maximum permissible runtime. This applies to all Airflow tasks, including sensor"